# Display WooCommerce category using ACF plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

My purpose is to display WooCommerce categories when editing a page based on a specific page template. I created a new field group in ACF plugin and assigned it to my page template. Then I created a new field associated to this group. Here are the settings :

- Field Label : Associated category
- Field Name : associated_category
- Field Type : Taxonomy
- Taxonomy : product_cat
- Field Type : Radio buttons
- Return Value : Term ID

When I'm editing a page with the template, it's working correctly : All my WooCommerce categories are listed and I can choose one of them. So far so good. BUT...

---

Now I'd like to display something in the front-office, on this template page : **the selected WooCommerce category's name** ! I tried to follow the ACF documentation but I can't manage to do it : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/taxonomy/

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you tried get_field('associated_category');? What's the output?

Comment: Thank you @Mûhámmàd, I already tried it but there's nothing appearing on the page... Tried it with "echo" and "print_r"...

Comment: Did you enabled the debug mode? is there any errors on log file?

Comment: pass the post ID to `get_field` as the second parameter.  `get_field` only works without that inside the loop.  `echo get_field('associated_category', get_the_ID());`